# React Redux <input> onChange update value question

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Which one is a better choice or best practice?

```
<input onChange={() => dispatch(/* some action (/)} />
```

or

```
<input onChange={() => this.setState({ value: newValue })} />
```

and then update the value in redux store when successfully submitted the form.

Comment: is the dispatch going to update the `value` similar to the local state or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think it totally depends on your requirement's.**

Both the method's has their own benifits.

Consider the scenario, where you want your form data to be `persist`, if user accidentally refreshes the page or page got refresh by any other way. In this case you can store the values in redux state directly, using:

```
<input onChange={() => dispatch(/* some action (/)} />
```

By doing this, your redux store is the single source of the truth. And you don't need to maintain separate state in your component. Your component will be a pure component.

Another scenario is, you don't bother about data to be persist, and want to store the data in redux store only once. In that case you can go for second option, i.e.

```
<input onChange={() => this.setState({ value: newValue })} />
```

By doing this, you have extra overhead of maintaining local state and updating later to redux store.

**You can choose any option as per your requirements.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using redux form you don't have to do this, redux form will save changes automatically in the store(not primarily ), so when you are using redux form you need to use `onClick` and use a helper in it, for example

```
<button
onClick={()=>
 this.clickhandlerhelper() }> 
 click here </button>
```

And in your helper ,it's like this

```
 Clickhandlerhelper(formvalues){
 This.props.myactionsave(formvalues)}
```

And then in your helper, you can save your data or anything you want
Hope it works for you and you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

This is a better approach.

```
<input onChange={this.handleInputChange} />

handleInputChange = value => {
    this.setState({ value })
}
```